# mysql : timestamp this month, last month and every month

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql table

```
amount  timestamp
3       1367638029
4       1367638029
5       1366445119
8       1366445200
```

How do i return the sum(amount) based on this month (not last 30 day) and last month something like below

```
            total amount
This month  7
Last month  13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This canbe done this way:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM yourtable
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) IN/BETWEEN ... -- consider YEAR(...)as well
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```